# Two generic interfaces referencing each other

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to write two generic class/interface Tile (`interface Tile<S extends Side<? extends Tile<S>>>`) and Side (`abstract class Side<T extends Tile<? extends Side<T>>>`) where the generic type of one interface has a reference to the other interface.

Now when I try to implement the Tile interface like so:

```
public abstract class TileImpl<S> implements Tile<S extends Side<? extends Tile<S>>
```

I have to keep writing the bound for the type S:

```
S extends Side<? extends Tile<S>>
```

How could I make this code working?

```
public interface Tile<S extends Side<? extends Tile<S>>> {

    S getSide(Direction d);

    /**
     * Returns true if the current instance of Tile and the Tile t
     * fit together.
     * @param t a tile adjacent to the current tile
     * @param d the position of the tile t with respect to the current tile
     * @return true if the current tile and the tile t fit together
     */
    boolean fitsWith(Tile<S> t, Direction d);
}

public abstract class Side<T extends Tile<? extends Side<T>>> {
    private final T parent;

    public Side(T parent) {
        this.parent = parent; 
    }

    public T getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question cries to be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please first try to explain your requiremens. Maybe another solution - far less complicated - fits your needs.

Comment: I agree that this is quite sophisticated. I'm using generics here to provide a default implementation of the method fitsWith so that classes that extend Tile can use it. My main motivation for using generics here is that the method fitsWith of a kind of tile will only accept tiles that have the same type of sides, and those sides must also reference the same type of tiles. I hope that my explanation is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public abstract class TileImpl<S> implements Tile<S extends Side<? extends Tile<S>>
```

Your problem here is that you have put bounds on `S` where it is used not where it is declared. So just move the bounds into the correct position.

```
public abstract class TileImpl<S extends Side<? extends Tile<S>>> implements Tile<S>
```